# Ploeh AutoFixture was unable to create an instance from System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject

Tags: c#, .net, autofixture

We have an MVC project with references to WCF services. Those references added `(ExtensionDataObject)ExtensionData` property to every DTO and Response object and now `AutoFixture` fails to create anonymous instances of these types.

Example:

```
public partial class SearchResultsDto : object, 
    System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, 
    System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    [global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData {
        get {
                return this.extensionDataField;
            }
        set {
                this.extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Code:

```
_fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
var dto = _fixture.CreateAnonymous<SearchResultsDto>();
```

Exception:

> Ploeh.AutoFixture.ObjectCreationException:
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.ObjectCreationException: AutoFixture was unable to
>   create an instance from
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject, most likely because
>   it has no public constructor, is an abstract or non-public type..

Question: Is there a way of registering this object within the AutoFixture, so that it instantiates it as `null` or anything else, which would let me do `CreateAnonymous` on all objects with `ExtensionData` property.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is:

```
fixture.Register<ExtensionDataObject>(() => null);
```

That registers to AutoFixture a specific way to initialize all the ExtensionDataObject, with the Func given. In this case the Func always returns null so you are good to go.

Comment: This works great. Is Chuck's answer and this one do the same, eventually?

Answer (score 16):

I hope someone will find it useful, I've managed to get it to work with the `PropertyTypeOmitter` class as per the [this thread](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/69):

```
public void Test()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customizations.Add(
        new PropertyTypeOmitter(
            typeof(ExtensionDataObject)));

    var person = fixture.CreateAnonymous<Person>();
}

internal class PropertyTypeOmitter : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    private readonly Type type;

    internal PropertyTypeOmitter(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

        this.type = type;
    }

    internal Type Type
    {
        get { return this.type; }
    }

    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var propInfo = request as PropertyInfo;
        if (propInfo != null && propInfo.PropertyType == type)
            return new OmitSpecimen();

        return new NoSpecimen();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since AutoFixture 3.x the last line of code triggers a warning caused by the contstructor call being marked as Obsolete. In order to remove it, change it to: new NoSpecimen()

Answer (score 3):

To make it bit DRYer and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> friendly, here is Spiros Dellaportases (thanks!) answer wrapped in fixture Customization:

```
public class OmitExtensionDataObjectPropertyCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Register<ExtensionDataObject>(() => null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you copying someone else's answer?

Comment: The explanation is in very first sentence of the answer. Should help people to keep their code DRY, especially if they are new to AutoFixture.