# how to initialize complex object for unit testing?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, moq, autofixture

**How does one initialize a complex object with random data for testing?**

I've got kind of a complex object that looks like this:

```
public class DynamicEntity
{
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
    public List<Entity> MappingEntityList { get; set; }
    public List<BaseAttributes> BaseAttributesList { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to initialize it with random data:

```
// Fixture setup
Fixture fixture = new Fixture();
DynamicEntity dynamicEntityFixture = fixture.Create<DynamicEntity>();
```

I am then setting up my mocked object to return this dynamicEntityFixture:

```
_mockedObject.Setup(x => x.GetEntityProperties("account"))
                          .Returns(() => dynamicEntityFixture);
```

When running the unit test I am getting:

> Ploeh.AutoFixture.ObjectCreationException : AutoFixture was unable to
>   create an instance from
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject, most likely because
>   it has no public constructor, is an abstract or non-public type.

How can I initialize a complex object with random data for testing?

Comment: You didn't tag with [tag:AutoFixture], but it seems you are using it. Did you try searching for exact error message? E.g. look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15478897/1997232).

Comment: This error is very common one when using `AutoFixture`. How does `Entity` and `BaseAttributes` classes look like?

Comment: @Sinatr your link worked!